# android ndk build fails on build-binary.mk:369

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have a big project with hundreds of c++ files that I am supposed to port to Android. I am new to the project and NDK as well. I got rid of most errors and the ndk build progresses up to here:

> Compile++ thumb  : mylib <= MyApp.cpp
>
> SharedLibrary  : libmylib.so
>
> ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/mylib/MyApp.o: In function `MyClass::MyFunction(unsigned long, void*, unsigned long long)':
>
> C:\Development/./jni/AClass.h:249: undefined reference to `MyClass::Function(unsigned long, void*, unsigned long long)'
>
> .... plenty of these error messages here...
>
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> /cygdrive/c/Android/android-ndk/android-ndk-r8/build/core/build-binary.mk:369: recipe for target `obj/local/armeabi/libmylib.so' failed
>
> make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libmylib.so] Error 1

it even goes to "SharedLibrary  : libmylib.so" now but then I get heaps of these errors "undefined reference" like above. The classes are included and the functions defined.

line 369 in build-binary.mk is:

> @ $(call host-mkdir,$(dir $@))

but I don't know what that means. I read something about permission problems with shared libraries and set all files to allow everything but that didnt change anything. could it be that mkdir fails for some reason? Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is my Android.mk file:

> LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
>
> include $(CLEAR_VARS)
>
> LOCAL_MODULE    := mylib
>
> LOCAL_SRC_FILES := MyApp.cpp
>
> LOCAL_CFLAGS := -D_Android_ -D_Debug_
>
> include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

Answer (score 0):

Likely one of three things are happening:

- You are not actually compiling the code for these functions, perhaps because it is surrounded by #ifdef or because the files in question are not being built.  You can check for the presence of .o files corresponding to their source.  You can also put #error in the body of the function and verify that the build fails there (I know it sounds silly, but it catches silly mistakes that waste your time)
- The functions are in an object file or library that is not being linked in.  In this case you need to add the missing piece to the linkage.
- The functions are in a different dynamic library which will be preloaded before the library you are building is loaded, or at least will get loaded before the functions which depend on them are loaded.  There is a special flag you can use to allow undefined symbols in shared libraries - I forget what it is, but you can look it up.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. MyApp.o and MyApp.o.d exist in obj\local\armeabi\objs\mylib

The functions are in my project and should go into the same library.

#error is not called in the body functions as it complains before that it isn't defined. but using #error in the place where the function is used showed me different errors which I didn't see before and which I will have to resolve first. I expect that the original errors are caused by a non functioning library which had errors that it didn't show me.
Ill try to resolve the other errors and come back in case that didn't resolve it.

Comment: Sounds like you are making progress.  One thing to keep in mind is that all of the C code should get compiled before any of it gets linked.  If the C code is going into the library a #error in it should happen before the undefined reference errer, as the latter is a linker error not a compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

Is the class MyClass defined in the MyApp.cpp?

If not, you need to add the MyClass source file in the LOCAL_SRC_FILES too, for example,

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := MyApp.cpp AClass.cpp.

Comment: yes it is defined. i think i might be having a problem with the compiler as the functions are not actually seen by the compiler ever. i have installed cygwin with all g++ and gcc packages, make and gdb and also eclipse cdt. but it seems that compiler isnt working right. since this is a java project using jni i don't have access to the c++ settings dialog in project properties and don't know enough about make files to get the compiler set up right. can i define the compiler manually from the make file?